# Mismatched input 'strategy' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

Good day, I'm new to Pine Script, please help to solve "Mismatched input 'strategy' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' " in strategy.
This error appears in 'strategy.entry'
Strategy:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vovulka

//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy")

// initialize stochastic oscillator
stoch_osc = stoch(length = 14)

// buy entry rule based on stochastic oscillator
if (stoch_osc.crossunder(50.0))
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, stop = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.01)

// calculate profit and loss
strategy.profits = strategy.position_avg_price ? strategy.position_size * (strategy.position_price - strategy.position_avg_price) : 0
strategy.losses = strategy.position_avg_price ? strategy.position_size * -(strategy.position_price - strategy.position_avg_price) : 0

// execute trading operations
if (stoch_osc.crossover(50.0))
strategy.close("buy")
if (strategy.long and strategy.position_size > 0)
strategy.order_type = strategy.market
strategy.order(strategy.long, "buy", qty = strategy.position_size, when = strategy.close_all, limitprice = strategy.position_price * 0.998)
```

Comment: I just realized this is chatGPT nonsense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is chatGPT generated code. Code uses imaginary functions and variables which don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how an if structure looks like:

```
if <expression>
    <local_block>
{else if <expression>
    <local_block>}
[else
    <local_block>]
```

The local blocks in conditional structures must be indented by four spaces or a tab.